# Can the rapper Drake get a criminal through Canadian immigration?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, criminal-records

The rapper Drake routinely brags in rap lyrics about his ability to get people convicted of crimes (such as a DUI) through Canadian customs.

From Genius, we can see [three examples](https://genius.com/11026525).

> [Gucci Mane]
>   I got so many felonies, I might can't never go to Canada
>   But Drake said he gon' pull some strings, so let me check my calendar

---

> [Drake] Luckily, I’m the greatest my country’s ever seen
>   So chances are I get the border to issue me clearance

---

> [Drake] Your girl got a DUI, I’ll make the calls to get y'all through customs
>   Tell your best friend, “Girl get your paperwork right”

---

Are there documented cases of a celebrity convincing Canadian authorities to let a criminal through the border?

Comment: Not even a head of a state could convince Canadian authorities to bypass the law. It doesn't work that way. The very charter starts with " Whereas Canada is founded upon principles that recognize the supremacy of God and *the rule of law*". Emphasis mine.

Comment: @chx I guess GW Bush got a special waiver for his [1976 criminal DUI conviction](http://abcnews.go.com/International/story?id=82199&page=1)

Comment: @chx So much for theory. In practice there's obviously a great deal more pragmatism going on.

Comment: Heads of states themselves have diplomatic passports and as such different law applies to them. What I was trying to say: they can't make people who don't have such get a pass.

Comment: This question may be suited to [Skeptics.SE].

Comment: @chx diplomatic passports are fairly useless.  Heads of state generally receive special treatment because they are heads of state (and diplomats receive it because of their diplomatic posts).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While it's highly unlikely CBSA gives one whit about Drake or what he says he can do, yes, it is possible to enter Canada with a criminal history.

[Overcome criminal convictions](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/inadmissibility/conviction.asp)

You have to apply for a Visa (get it approved), qualify for a waiver (get that approved), then convince CBSA at the border to admit you.

Season 1, Episode 2 of [Border Security](http://natgeotv.com/ca/border-security/about) Canada features actor Cory Feldman being admitted to Canada.  He had to go through secondary due to his criminal history.

Comment: This question doesn't clarify the powers held by the rapper Drake, but I guess it sufficiently answers the broader topic.